# spark-shell showing "Error initializing SparkContext. org.apache.spark.SparkException: Yarn application has already ended!"

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, hadoop-yarn

we installed hadoop 2.7.4 and spark 2.2.1 but when we run spark-shell command it shows below error

```
ERROR SparkContext: Error initializing SparkContext.
org.apache.spark.SparkException: Yarn application has already ended! It might have been killed or unable to launch application master.
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.waitForApplication(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.start(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:173)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:509)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:236)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
23/05/01 08:22:26 WARN YarnSchedulerBackend$YarnSchedulerEndpoint: Attempted to request executors before the AM has registered!
23/05/01 08:22:26 WARN MetricsSystem: Stopping a MetricsSystem that is not running
Traceback (most recent call last):
  ", line 400, in <module>
    .config('spark.debug.maxToStringFields', 1000)
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/sql/session.py", line 173, in getOrCreate
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 334, in getOrCreate
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 118, in __init__
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 180, in _do_init
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/pyspark.zip/pyspark/context.py", line 273, in _initialize_context
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/java_gateway.py", line 1401, in __call__
  File "/opt/spark/python/lib/py4j-0.10.4-src.zip/py4j/protocol.py", line 319, in get_return_value
py4j.protocol.Py4JJavaError: An error occurred while calling None.org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.
: org.apache.spark.SparkException: Yarn application has already ended! It might have been killed or unable to launch application master.
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.waitForApplication(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:85)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.cluster.YarnClientSchedulerBackend.start(YarnClientSchedulerBackend.scala:62)
    at org.apache.spark.scheduler.TaskSchedulerImpl.start(TaskSchedulerImpl.scala:173)
    at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.<init>(SparkContext.scala:509)
    at org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext.<init>(JavaSparkContext.scala:58)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at the sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at py4j.reflection.MethodInvoker.invoke(MethodInvoker.java:247)
    at py4j.reflection.ReflectionEngine.invoke(ReflectionEngine.java:357)
    at py4j.Gateway.invoke(Gateway.java:236)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.invokeConstructor(ConstructorCommand.java:80)
    at py4j.commands.ConstructorCommand.execute(ConstructorCommand.java:69)
    at py4j.GatewayConnection.run(GatewayConnection.java:214)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Build step 'Execute shell' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

what could be the possible reason please help someone
i am not able to find the exact logs from server , could someone suggest exact pathfor logs ?

Comment: Logs say YARN has stopped, or was never running. Can you share YARN logs instead (which are in the directory where you downloaded hadoop, by default)

Comment: No logs are generated

Comment: Did you actually start YARN? Please clarify what commands you're running and how are you "installing hadoop"

Comment: yes we have spark and hadoop installed in ec2 instance and we are configured EMR for spark-submit, we added EMR cluster details in yarn-site.xml and hdfs-site.xml

Comment: I suggest contacting EMR support, then. Otherwise, you need to share your yarn-site file here, and still show us that YARN is actually running and reachable

Comment: @OneCricketeer
sure 
how can we confirm yarn is running and reachable with JPS command ?

Comment: `jps` shows running Java processes. Has nothing to do with network configuration. You would use `netstat` for that, where you can compare the process ID from `jps` output to bound/listening ports... Still, you shouldn't need to manage your own EC2 instances; EMR does all this for you, and you should be able to submit Spark code directly to it - https://docs.aws.amazon.com/emr/latest/ReleaseGuide/emr-spark-submit-step.html